# What's the restriction on distance between pointers of certain type in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose I have two pointers to type `T`:

```
T* first = ...// whatever
T* second = ... //whatever else
```

Can I be sure that the distance between those two pointers can never exceed:

`((size_t)(-1))/sizeof(T)`?

Comment: I don't think so, it depends on how and when the memory is allocated for these 2 T objects

Comment: I think that's true as long as `size_t` is at least as large as the pointer. But I'm unsure if `size_t` is guaranteed to be at least the size of a pointer. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Mystical: what do you mean by "size of a pointer"? The size of a pointer is usually 4 or 8 bytes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only compute the distance between two pointers (subtract one pointer from another) if both pointers point to elements in the same array, or to one-past-the-end of the same array.

If the two pointers meet that constraint, then yes, the absolute value of the difference between the two pointers cannot exceed `((size_t)(-1)) / sizeof(T)` because `size_t` must be wide enough to represent the size of any object in bytes.

If the two pointers do not meet that constraint, then there's no guarantee at all.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. What use of `ptrdiff_t` then?

Comment: Given `T* p`, the type of `p - p` is `std::ptrdiff_t`.  The C++ Standard expressly states that a pointer subtraction operation may overflow, yielding undefined behavior (C++11 5.7/6).

Comment: +1, when pointers don't meet those constraints the behaviour is undefined.